# Path set to cyclic becomes twisted at the join?

Tags: modeling, objects

I have created a path and set it to be cyclic. However, instead of just appearing smooth there is a twist where the ends meet. I can't seem to find a solution.
[image: twisted cyclic path]

Comment: Check your curve tilting

Comment: I have checked the tilt of each point but nothing seems to affect the twist

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem. For some reason having the two end points that quite far away from each other created the artefact (although I'm not entirely sure why).